# Filter by longest sequence and delete shorter sequences by duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a problem and I don't really know how to solve it with Python.

I want to filter my output of words and sequences and I want to remove 'duplicates'. I put duplicates in quotation marks because they are not *real* duplicates.
The filter should prefer the longest possible sequence **without** any duplicate words. See the following example for clarity.

Example output:

```
out: ['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'quick fox', 'brown fox', 'grey wolf', 'brown hare', 'quick brown fox']
```

After it's going through the filter, only `['quick brown fox', 'grey wolf', 'brown hare']` should be in the result.
I don't know if it's possible to filter `['brown']` but keeping **both** ['quick brown fox'] and ['brown hare']...

I hope that I described my problem clearly enough.
Any help and ideas are very welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have an idea of what is the rule that divide words in list into GOOD or BAD, othrwise giving a general answer (that can work on many inputs) is impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you need to find all sequences that are not subsets of any other sequence.

Let's proceed like this:

- convert each item into a pair `text`, `set of words`
- sort the list by the set length descending
- for every pair, check if the `set` component is a subset of any preceding set
- if not, add to the result

---

```
inp = ['quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'quick fox', 'brown fox', 'grey wolf', 'brown hare', 'quick brown fox']

pairs = [
    [s, set(s.split())]
    for s in inp
]

pairs.sort(key=lambda p: -len(p[1]))

res = [
    pair[0]
    for n, pair in enumerate(pairs)
    if all(not pair[1].issubset(prev[1]) for prev in pairs[:n])
]

print(res) # ['quick brown fox', 'grey wolf', 'brown hare']
```

Comment: Thanks al lot! Exactly what I was searching for! Your explanation is also very clear, great! :)